# Why is there a 0 byte file "SFX.CAB" on my C: Drive?

Tags: windows-10, filesystems

On my C: drive, there is a seemingly randomly named folder `22bd0e40ae58e6d4e29040`. Inside this folder is a single 0 byte file named `SFX.CAB`.

[image: Just a random 0 byte SFX.CAB]

[I've read that .cab files may contain driver files](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-files/deleting-sfxcab-files/d80a2c14-4b70-469c-afd2-684124573e65), but last I checked, you can't fit drivers into a 0 byte file.

Where could this file have come from? Should I delete it?

Comment: Given that it was created over 3 years ago, yes, delete away

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "22bd0e40ae58e6d4e29040" is not random folder, it is a folder created by one of the windows updates, used in case of a roll back.

usually sfx.cab has drivers in it, and the size will vary (I see most of them around 130 MB).

You can delete it but I would recommend using the drive cleanup utility instead, unless you know what you are doing.

For example I do delete most of the KB created folders but I know that I don't need roll back or system restore due to data being on a separate drive and the ease of reinstalling from USB is faster for me

Comment: Do you know which Windows update may have created it?

Comment: While I agree it's not random, and was created by an update 3 years ago, this IMO does not have even factual statements

Comment: Would love to understand what you would consider facts, happy to add or edit the answer to improve but I think it does answer the question